Pulumi (Azure-Native): API connection to Blob Storage with Managed Identity
I am trying to create an API connection with Pulumi (Azure Native provider) and typescript.
The resource is being created, but it's missing the authentication type 'Managed identity'.
Documentation is not clear (neither Pulumi, nor Microsoft). I tried to compare with Bicep templates, but didn't work out Bicep solution.
I tried to add 'parametersValueSet' as in Bicep, but it doesn't seem to affect how the resource is deployed to Azure. The API connection resource has an error: 'Test connection failed. Error 'Key 'AccessKey' not found in connection profile.'
The Pulumi resource:
const blobStorageApiConnection = new web.Connection("blob-storage-api-connection", {
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    location: currentLocation,
    connectionName: "blob-storage-api-connection",
    properties: {
        //@ts-expect-error
        parametersValueSet: {
            name: "managedIdentityAuth",
            values: {}
        },
        customParameterValues: {},
        parameterValues: {
            accountName: saEGName,
        },
        api: {
            id: `/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${currentLocation}/managedApis/azureblob`,
        },
        testLinks: [
            {
                requestUri: `https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob/extensions/proxy/testconnection?api-version=2018-07-01-preview`,
                method: "get"
            }
        ]
    }
});

The error in the Azure Portal:

The authentication field in the API Connection parameters is empty:

I expect to have this field set to 'Managed identity':

When creating the API connection from level of Azure Portal, everything works fine. The issue is only when working with Pulumi on it.
To give a context, I want to use this API connection in Logic App, in order to connect to that Blob Storage.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?
Any comments appreciated! :)
